# I finish a work about “docker” and it give me the url, but i can't open it. What should I do to see the website?

Tags: linux, networking, docker

[image]

[image]
 As you can see, it finished and show "Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/". But when I copy this url to my firefox, it shows failed. Is I used url in a wrong way or something else I did wrong？ So, what could I do to see the website? Any words from anyone could help. Thanks a lot.

ps：I used “http：//127.0.0.1：5000/” but it does'nt work.

Comment: And if you try port 8888 on 127.0.0.1?

Comment: well，I saw the website. It's intersting. I mean how do you konw this url?

Comment: You explicitly set up a mapping between the local port 8888 and port 5000 in the container with `-p 8888:5000` on the command line...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option `-p 8888:5000` that you use on the command line when you start your container indicates that you want to map the local port 8888 to port 5000 in the Docker container.

Therefore, accessing `http://127.0.0.1:8888` would most likely access your Flask application in the container.

See the section [EXPOSE (incoming ports)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports) in the documentation for `docker run`.